# missing variable

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I wrote this method to take an `int[]b` then creates an array of `int[] Per` and fill it by taking each index `i` in `b` and uses another method to return an `int` value to be as an index of the new array Per with value of `b[i]`, but the small and stupid problem is it says can't find symbol `i` in line  `Per [index-1]= b[i]`;
any idea

```
 public static int [] intial(int [] b)
        {   
            int [] Per =new int [64];
            int index;
            for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)

                index=itable(i);
                Per [index-1]= b[i];


            return Per;
        }
```

Comment: The convention is to start variables with a lowercase letter. Just to mention it:)

Comment: Get in the habit of telling your IDE to auto-format the text often.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)

    index=itable(i);
    Per [index-1]= b[i];
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
    index=itable(i);
    Per [index-1]= b[i];
}
```

Not including the braces `{ }` in the loop make the compiler consider the first line only as the body of the loop and since `i` is a loop variable it wont be visible. Including the braces changes all this and make the two statement part of the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this line :

```
int index, b;
```

you are creating a second variable named "b", hiding the variable given as an argument (int[] b).

And please use lowercase letters at the beginning your variable names. "Per" is confusing, i thought it was a class name. Use "per" instead.

Here is a better version of what you are doing :

```
public static int [] intial(int [] b)
{   
    int [] per = new int [64];
    for(int i=0; i<b.length; ++)
        per [itable(i)-1]= b[i];

     return per;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int [] intial(int [] b) {   
    int[] Per = new int[64];
    int index,b;
    for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
        index=itable(i);
        Per[index-1] = b[i];
    }
    return Per;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you're trying to achieve, however the error you are getting is because you are re-declaring a variable named `b`. If you look you can see that you named the parameter to your method `b`, as well as declaring an int variable named `b`. To get this to compile you'll either need to rename the method parameter, or the local variable.

Additionally, if in the line `Per [index-1]= b[i];` you intend to reference the local variable, you will need to change its declaration to be an array of int.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : After the question is edited, I am not sure.

There are many things wrong in this.

```
public static int [] intial(int [] b)
    {   
        int Per []=new int [64];
        int index, b;  // b is redefined

        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
            index=itable(i);    // what is itable???
            Per [index-1]= b[i];  // what is index??


        return Per;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int [] intial(int [] b) 
        {    
            int [] Per =new int [64]; 
            int index; // varible b was atypo
            for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){ //here was the error because i did not wrote {}

                index=itable(i); //method returns int value less than 64
                Per [index-1]= b[i]; }


            return Per; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static int[] intial(int[] b) {
    int[] Per = new int[64];      
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
      Per[itable(i)-1] = b[i];    
    return Per;
  }
```